# Getting error "DLL load failed while importing rect: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" while importing package

Tags: python, c++, windows, ffmpeg, cython

I am using cython package to call Cpp API and in my cpp code i am using ffmpeg library and able to build my code successfully using bellow command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc
```

but when i try to import generated pyd file then i get error

```
PS D:\SiVUE\Backend\Cython\demo> python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing rect: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

My entire code is provided bellow

```
header file
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"
    #include "libavutil/dict.h"
}

using namespace std;

namespace shapes 
{
    class Rectangle {
        public:
            int x0, y0, x1, y1;
            Rectangle();
            Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
            ~Rectangle();
            int getArea();
            int ffmpegFile();
            void getSize(int* width, int* height);
            void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
}

#endif
```

Rectangle.Cpp file in ffmpegFile() i am calling mostly ffmpeg API

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.hpp"

namespace shapes {
    

    // Default constructor
    Rectangle::Rectangle () {}

    // Overloaded constructor
    Rectangle::Rectangle (int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
        this->x0 = x0;
        this->y0 = y0;
        this->x1 = x1;
        this->y1 = y1;
    }

    // Destructor
    Rectangle::~Rectangle () {}

    // Return the area of the rectangle
    int Rectangle::getArea () {
        return 10;
    }

    // Get the size of the rectangle.
    // Put the size in the pointer args
    void Rectangle::getSize (int *width, int *height) {
        (*width) = x1 - x0;
        (*height) = y1 - y0;
    }

    // Move the rectangle by dx dy
    void Rectangle::move (int dx, int dy) {
        this->x0 += dx;
        this->y0 += dy;
        this->x1 += dx;
        this->y1 += dy;
    }
    int Rectangle::ffmpegFile()
    {
        AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = NULL;
        AVDictionaryEntry *tag = NULL;
        int ret = 0;
        char* filename = "D:\\Discovery.mp4";

        if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)))
            return ret;

        if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
            return ret;
        }

        while ((tag = av_dict_get(fmt_ctx->metadata, "", tag, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)))
            printf("%s=%s\n", tag->key, tag->value);

        avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Rectangle.pxd file declaration for cpp file function and variable

```
cdef extern from "Rectangle.cpp":
    pass
cdef extern from "Rectangle.hpp" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()
        void getSize(int* width, int* height)
        void move(int, int)
        int ffmpegFile()
```

rect.pyx file i am calling cpp API

```
# distutils: language = c++

from Rectangle cimport Rectangle

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect  # Hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)

    def get_area(self):
        return self.c_rect.getArea()

    def get_size(self):
        cdef int width, height
        self.c_rect.getSize(&width, &height)
        return width, height

    def move(self):
        print(self.c_rect.ffmpegFile())
```

setup.py
I provided pyx file and ffmpeg library path as well as include path

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize 

sfc_module = [Extension('rect', sources = ['rect.pyx'],
                       include_dirs = ['D:\\SiVUE\\Backend\\Cython\\demo\\ffmpeg\\include\\'],
                       library_dirs = ['D:\\SiVUE\\Backend\\Cython\\demo\\ffmpeg\\lib\\'],
                       libraries = ['avcodec','avdevice','avfilter','avformat','avutil','postproc','swresample','swscale'],
                       language='c++')]

setup(name = 'superfastcode', version = '1.0',
    description = 'Python Package with superfastcode C++ extension',
    ext_modules = cythonize(sfc_module),
    include_dirs = ['D:\\SiVUE\\Backend\\Cython\\demo\\ffmpeg\\include\\']
    )
```

Thank You

Comment: And your libraries are 32bit?

Comment: yes i am using 32bit library

Comment: So what changed since the first version of your question, that it builds now? Your error still shows that there is  a mismatch between 32 and 64 bit exe/dll/pyd. This was easy to get with Python2 but not that easy with Python3. What is the name of the resulting pyd?

Comment: Btw please don't change a question (almost) completely next time, but ask a new one.